# Is volley service calls are asynchronous?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask, android-volley

I am newbie to android ,i have a dout regarding service calls in android.Which service calls are reliable either synchronous or asynchronous?and if asynchronous i am using volley in my application,is it is asynchronous?Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Volley makes the request asynchronously on the worker's thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every Volley request which takes a listener for example, success and fail listeners, is asynchronous and by default I want to say that almost all are asynchronous.

For more information you can read more in Volley's documentation.

Comment: Thanks for reply @galvan...so its better to use asynchronous calls,right?

Comment: Answer with a guess. Great